# Logging On/Off in EntLib

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

is there a setting in the config file that can turn the logging on or off in EntLib.
There are posts showing how to do this programatically but I am interested in doing it through the config file.

I am using EntLib 5.

here is the config

```
 <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
        <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
            log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
        <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            fileName="c:\\Log\\wclog.log" header=""
            formatter="Text Formatter" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            template="Timestamp:{timestamp}  Method: {title}, {category} {message}"
            name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
        <add switchValue="All" name="General">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
        <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </allEvents>
        <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </notProcessed>
        <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </errors>
    </specialSources>
```

Regards.

Comment: I answered below, but I'd like to know Why you want to turn them off via the config file?  If it's because it's a testing or development environment, you'll may want to look into the delta's and different environment configuration files.  They're pretty sweet once you get used to them:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664395(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways to disable logging.  As mentioned one is to set the category switch value to "Off":

```
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
        <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
            log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
        <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            fileName="c:\\Log\\wclog.log" header=""
            formatter="Text Formatter" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            template="Timestamp:{timestamp}  Method: {title}, {category} {message}"
            name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
        <add switchValue="All" name="General">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
        <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </allEvents>
        <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </notProcessed>
        <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
            <listeners>
                <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </errors>
    </specialSources>
```

You can also disable individual trace listeners by setting the filter property of the trace listener itself to "Off".

Probably the easiest way to globally disable logging is to use the Logging Enabled Filter:

```
    <logFilters>
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            enabled="false" name="Logging Enabled Filter" />
    </logFilters>
```

Then just set "true" or "false" to enable or disable logging.  Filters also have the benefit of executing first in the "logging pipeline" so it should have better performance than setting individual trace listeners to "Off".

Answer (score 2):

Although not ideal, here's an easy way that should work - comment out the listeners:

```
<categorySources>
    <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
            <!-- <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" /> -->
        </listeners>
    </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
    <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
           <!--  <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />  -->
        </listeners>
    </allEvents>
    <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
           <!--  <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />  -->
        </listeners>
    </notProcessed>
    <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <!--   <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />  -->
        </listeners>
    </errors>
</specialSources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the switchValue of your categorySources to "Off"

Comment: Hi Tuan, I have added the config file. The switchValue is 'All' here but I tried with 'Off'. Still does not work.

Comment: So you set it on the Flat File Trace Listener, and it's still writing to C:\Log\wcLog.log? Is this a Web app or a different application type? Also, have you tried setting the tracingEnabled attribute at the top to false?